# How to show div data by on click event on selector using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I am new to jQuery and confused about simple logic and need your help to sort the mess. I am using HTML, CSS, jQuery to display some data by on click the jQuery event on selector '.class'.
I have successfully opened the data for the first time for a single div panel. But if I used the same HTML twice then both of the panels display data at the same. Below is the code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".flip").click(function () {                  
        jQuery(this).siblings(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.panel, .flip {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}
.flip{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.cards-header.flip {
    background-color: #001c47;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- navigation end -->
        <div class="heading-wrapper">
            <h1>Ingredient of the Month</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="cards-header flip">      
                Year - 2022
            </div>
            <div class="panel ingredients-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="#" title="Shea Butter" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="" alt="Shea Butter" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>January'22, Shea Butter</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cards-header flip">      
                Year - 2021
            </div>
            <div class="panel ingredients-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="https://example.com/highlights/ingredient-of-the-month/carrot-seed-oil.html" title="Carrot Seed Oil" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-carrot-seed-oil.jpg" alt="Carrot Seed Oil" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>December'21, Carrot Seed Oil</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/olive-oil.html" title="Olive Oil" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-olive-oil.jpg" alt="Olive Oil" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>November'21, Olive Oil</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/lemon.html" title="Lemon" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-lemon.jpg" alt="Lemon" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>October'21, Lemon</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/lycopene.html" title="Lycopene" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-lycopene.jpg" alt="Lycopene" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>September'21, Lycopene</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/peach.html" title="Peach" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-peach.jpg" alt="Peach" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>August'21, Peach</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/cucumber.html" title="Cucumber" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-cucumber.jpg" alt="Cucumber" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>July'21, Cucumber</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/avocado.html" title="Avocado" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-avocado.jpg" alt="Avocado" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>June'21, Avocado</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/watermelon.html" title="Watermelon" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-watermelon.jpg" alt="Watermelon" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>May'21, Watermelon</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/coffee.html" title="Coffee" target="_blank" ><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-cofee.jpg" alt="Coffee" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>April'21, Coffee</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/kakaduplum-completed.html" title="Kakadu Plum" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-kakaduplum.jpg" alt="Kakadu Plum"  /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>March'21, Kakadu Plum</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So I want to open one by one i.e. when someone clicks on the year 2021 then it will open its data and if someone clicks on 2022 then that year div data open.
How to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Use `next` instead of `siblings`

```
JQuery(document).ready(function() {
    JQuery(".flip").click(function () {                  
        JQuery(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Working codepen. https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/zYEWxqR

Comment: hey mate can we make it simple that both year showing the data and as when someone click on particular year then the rest of other year data will closed automatically and simultaneously.

Comment: try to remove ``display: none;`` from ``.panel``

Comment: I want like this if I click on year 2021 then 2022 closed and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".flip").click(function () {                  
        jQuery(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
.panel, .flip {
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 28px;
}
.panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
}
.flip{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.cards-header.flip {
    background-color: #001c47;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- navigation end -->
        <div class="heading-wrapper">
            <h1>Ingredient of the Month</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="cards-header flip">      
                Year - 2022
            </div>
            <div class="panel ingredients-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="#" title="Shea Butter" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="" alt="Shea Butter" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>January'22, Shea Butter</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cards-header flip">      
                Year - 2021
            </div>
            <div class="panel ingredients-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="https://example.com/highlights/ingredient-of-the-month/carrot-seed-oil.html" title="Carrot Seed Oil" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-carrot-seed-oil.jpg" alt="Carrot Seed Oil" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>December'21, Carrot Seed Oil</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/olive-oil.html" title="Olive Oil" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-olive-oil.jpg" alt="Olive Oil" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>November'21, Olive Oil</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/lemon.html" title="Lemon" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-lemon.jpg" alt="Lemon" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>October'21, Lemon</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/lycopene.html" title="Lycopene" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-lycopene.jpg" alt="Lycopene" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>September'21, Lycopene</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/peach.html" title="Peach" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-peach.jpg" alt="Peach" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>August'21, Peach</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/cucumber.html" title="Cucumber" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-cucumber.jpg" alt="Cucumber" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>July'21, Cucumber</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/avocado.html" title="Avocado" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-avocado.jpg" alt="Avocado" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>June'21, Avocado</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/watermelon.html" title="Watermelon" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-watermelon.jpg" alt="Watermelon" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>May'21, Watermelon</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/coffee.html" title="Coffee" target="_blank" ><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-cofee.jpg" alt="Coffee" /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>April'21, Coffee</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="ingredient-img-wrapper">
                                <a href="ingredient-of-the-month/kakaduplum-completed.html" title="Kakadu Plum" target="_blank"><img class="img-fluid" src="./assets/img/Carousel-kakaduplum.jpg" alt="Kakadu Plum"  /></a>
                                <div class="ingredient-month-wrapper">
                                    <h2>March'21, Kakadu Plum</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".flip").click(function(e) {
  $(this).next().slideToggle()
})
```

https://codepen.io/hardik9193/pen/yLzKNEZ